# Navigate back to previous page within a container/div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm displaying `page2` component after clicking the button as the `setShowForm` sets my state to true. So the problem I'm having now is how do I navigate back to my **Page1** component as I have to display `Page3` in `Page1` so the ternary expression might seems a little bit complicated. I've tried using `React-router-dom` and `useHistory`, both of them doesnt work as I'm not switching between pages, just within a `div`.

```js
<div className={styles.ticketBox}>
 { !showForm ? (
      //some UI code
      <div className={styles.whitelistBox}>
          <Button className={styles.whiteListToggleButton} shape="round" onClick={() => setShowForm(() => true)}>Whitelist</Button>
      </div>
</div>
) : (
    <Page2 />
)}
```

Comment: You're displaying <div>s conditionally, based on state variables. Which means "going back" is really "resetting state to the previous/original value". Consider using an integer state instead of a boolean state, since a bool can only store two distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close, but to `setShowForm` you don't want to pass a function in, you just want to set it to `true`, ex:

```js
// defining useState variables
const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

// setting to true
setShowForm(true)

// setting to true on click
onClick={() => setShowForm(true)}
```

Comment: Got it! But how do I navigate from `Page2` back to `Page1`?

Comment: You'll need to pass the `setShowForm` function into your page component, ex: `<PageTwo setShowForm={setShowForm} />`. You can then use that in your component to `setShowForm(false)` on some click or whatever it is you want, but you pass the `useState` setter into the other component to toggle back to the original page. If you want a bunch of pages you may need a more sophisticated approach